# How to paste filtered values into a column in Excel using VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an Excel file which has a range of data in A:K. I'm creating a macro that when run will look at the data in the range and then paste values into column M that match certain criteria. The values to be pasted are in column A but only if the value in column D is within the MIN of column D + 20.

I'm currently using this formula in M2, but i need it to be in VBA macro form. That's where I'm getting stuck.

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A), (D:D<(MIN(D:D)+20)), "No results"))`

[image]

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please share the code you've got so far. Some sample data and screenshots would also be helpful. What is the name of the worksheet?

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my post with a screenshot. As you will see, I've got the formula in column M. I want to make this into a macro where I do not need to enter the formula. I would just run the macro and it would put the values from that formula in column M.

Answer (score 0):

### Retrieve Unique Conditionally Looked-Up Values

- These will return an item if it has at least once satisfied the condition as the given formula would suggest.
- In the lookup (less-than) column (`D`), no error values are allowed while blanks are ignored (not treated as zeros).
- In the return column (`A`), blanks and errors are ignored (not returned).

**Excel Formula**

```
=LET(ldata,A:A,mdata,D:D,no_results,"No results",
IF(COUNT(mdata)=0,no_results,
    TOCOL(UNIQUE(FILTER(ldata,(mdata<(MIN(mdata)+20)*(mdata<>"")))),3)))
```

[image]

**VBA**

```vb
Sub LookupLessThan()

    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Lookup Less Than"
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_LESS_THAN_FIRST_CELL As String = "D1"
    Const SRC_RETURN_COLUMN As String = "A"
    Const SRC_MIN_DIFFERENCE As Double = 20
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "M1"
    Const NO_RESULTS As String = "No results"
    Const CLEAR_BELOW As Boolean = True
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim slrg As Range, srCount As Long, dr As Long
    
    With sws.Range(SRC_LESS_THAN_FIRST_CELL)
        srCount = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If srCount < 1 Then GoTo WriteResult
        Set slrg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    If Application.Count(slrg) = 0 Then GoTo WriteResult
    Dim Minimum As Double: Minimum = Application.Min(slrg) + SRC_MIN_DIFFERENCE
    
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_RETURN_COLUMN)
    
    Dim slData() As Variant, rData() As Variant
    
    If srCount = 1 Then
       ReDim slData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): slData(1, 1) = slrg.Value
       ReDim rData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): rData(1, 1) = srrg.Value
    Else
       slData = slrg.Value
       rData = srrg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim slVal As Variant, srVal As Variant, sr As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        slVal = slData(sr, 1)
        If VarType(slVal) = vbDouble Then
            srVal = rData(sr, 1)
            If Not IsError(srVal) Then
                If Len(srVal) > 0 Then
                    If slVal < Minimum Then
                        If Not dict.Exists(srVal) Then
                            dict(srVal) = Empty
                            dr = dr + 1
                            rData(dr, 1) = srVal
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next sr
    
WriteResult:
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    
    With dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
        If dr = 0 Then
            .Value = NO_RESULTS
        Else
            .Resize(dr).Value = rData
        End If
        If CLEAR_BELOW Then
            .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```